# How do you create an array of simple integers in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

Why is this code giving the error

> Cannot call 'ema' with 'length'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: integer`

How can I make the integers any more simple?

```
// Define EMA lengths
length1 = input(9)
length2 = input(21)
length3 = input(34)
length4 = input(55)
length5 = input(89)
emaLengths = array.from(length1, length2, length3, length4, length5)

plot(ema(close, array.get(emaLengths,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your end goal is or why you don't directly pass `length2` to `ema()` but `array.get()` returns `series[int]`. `ema()`, however, expects an `integer` as its `length` argument.

As a workaround, you can use the `sma()` to calculate the `ema()`. `sma()` expects `series[integer]` as its `length` argument so it will work in your case.

```
//@version=4
study("My script", overlay=true)

// Define EMA lengths
length1 = input(9)
length2 = input(21)
length3 = input(34)
length4 = input(55)
length5 = input(89)
emaLengths = array.from(length1, length2, length3, length4, length5)

pine_ema(src, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

plot(pine_ema(close, array.get(emaLengths,1)))
plot(ema(close, length2))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what to make of this answer. I am asking how to make an array of simple integers. But you have instead made and alternative ema function. Why does pine script say that my simple integers are series integers?

Comment: I am trying to work with arrays in for loops. My question is just a simplified example.